Why I get two different minimum when using simplex and Newton-cg method?
Given the function
$$
f(x_1, x_2) = e^{x_1} (4x_1^2 + 2x_2^2 + 4x_1x_2 + 2x_2 + 1)
$$
I have found the minimum at point $[0.5,-1]$. Then working numerically I had to use two different algorithms in sagemath to find the global minimum (one algorithm should use derivative and the other not) starting from the point $(-1,2)$. I used simplex for non derivative and Newton-cg method for derivative-based. When I ran the code for the simplex method the output was $\sim(0.5,−1)$ which is close to the correct minimum point, but ncg method gave the result $\sim(−18.8,4.22)$. Can anyone explain why the difference between the two?

Simplex is only for linear programs! This is a nonlinear objective.

It is not uncommon for search algorithms for global minimums and maximums to head in the wrong direction and then stop at a point where machine precision isn't adequate.  Good starting values are your best friends.  Contour plots are also helpful especially if the bivariate function is complicated.

I don't require any software for this, the exercise does. It also requires to comment on the two results that's why I was wondering. Thank you

Your function can be rewritten as $$e^{x_1}\left(\left(2x_1+x_2\right)^2+\left(x_2+1\right)^2\right)$$ which is a paraboloid damped by an exponential (on the left half plane side) The function is completely nonnegative, with a zero at the vertex of the paraboloid but also approaching zero as $x_1\to-\infty$. The function is continuous so it must have a point where it stops increasing and turns back around. It's not a coincidence your derivative approached failed, it leads us to conclude that you ran afoul of a turning point aka some sort of local max which disrupts derivative algorithms.

@Sean Roberson, there is also a Simplex Method, a.k.a. Nelder-Mead https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method  for nonlinear objectives. It has no relation to the Simplex Method for Linear Programming, other than the name.
